# Answer from google mini smart home

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

Is there a way to create a smart home app an let google only reply ok instead of a complet sentence ? Is there a JSON to specify some where **?**

Answer (score 0):

Action responses can only be defined for [conversational Actions through Scenes and prompts](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/build/conversation).

You can find the available API calls for Smart Home and Local Fulfillment on the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits).